# Merging two sorted halves of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement this mergeSort function in C++ and I am having little success. The algorithm that I have created so far sorts the two halves of the array, however,  I know that I need some code before the return and after the sort of the second half that will merge the two halves of the array together. This is where I am running into some issues, and I can not figure out how to actually merge the two together.

```
int mergeSort(empType A[], int first, int last)
{

int mid = (first + last + 1) / 2;       // get midpoint
int comp = 0;                       // holds # of comparisons
empType tempArray;

// Loop to middle, start at first + 1
for (int i = first + 1; i < mid; i++)
{
    // if given score < previous
    if (A[i].Score < A[i - 1].Score)
    {
        // set j = what i is at in original for loop
        // loop to first + 1 and decrement
        for (int j = i; j > first + 1; j--)
        {
            // if element's score < previous
            if (A[j].Score < A[j - 1].Score)
            {
                tempArray.ID = A[j].ID;             // Put ID into tempArray
                tempArray.Score = A[j].Score;       // Put Score into tempArray
                A[j].ID = A[j - 1].ID;              // Move on to next ID element
                A[j].Score = A[j - 1].Score;        // Move on to next Score element
                A[j - 1].ID = tempArray.ID;         // Put next ID into tempArray
                A[j - 1].Score = tempArray.Score;   // Put next Score into tempArray
                comp++;                             // Increase computations
            }
        }
    }
}
// loop from middle to last elements
for (int i = mid; i < last; i++)
{
    // if current score < previous
    if (A[i].Score < A[i - 1].Score)
    {
        for (int j = i; j > mid + 1; j--)
        {
            if (A[j].Score < A[j - 1].Score)
            {
                tempArray.ID = A[j].ID;
                tempArray.Score = A[j].Score;
                A[j].ID = A[j - 1].ID;
                A[j].Score = A[j - 1].Score;
                A[j - 1].ID = tempArray.ID;
                A[j - 1].Score = tempArray.Score;
                comp++;
            }
        }
    }
}




return comp;    // return the number of comparisons
}
```

Comment: C++? What about starting to use `std::vector` instead of plain array?

Comment: I would have rather used that but the requirements are to use an array

Comment: Are you allowed to `std::swap( A[j], A[j-1] )` instead of doing it yourself? much easier to maintain.

Comment: 1) You can write an assignment operator for `empType` which will make this code more readable. 2) At a glance this looks like bubble-sorting, not merge-sorting; where is the part that ought to merge the two arrays? 3) Have you tried writing a function that merges two sorted arrays *and does nothing else?*

Comment: Er, this isn't a merge sort. A merge sort arbitrarily divides the array into two (or more) partitions (performing _no other_ operation on them), then recurses on each subarray. The actual sorting occurs when you merge partitions back together.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). It will help.